# How to add a checkbox in wix installer

Tags: installation, wix, backup, conditional-statements

I am working with the wix installer. I have implemented a folder backup functionality during my product installation. I need to add a checkbox in my setup installation to ask the user for the backup. if they check the checkbox ,then only the system needs to take the backup. 
 how to add the checkbox in the installer and how to add a condition in my wix file to take a backup.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 4):

This should give you an idea: http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/

Answer (score 3):

Be warned:  the Checkbox control can be counter intuitive.  The checkbox does not choose between two values such as 0 and 1 or true and false.  Checkbox values work more like #define in C/C++.  If the property is set to any value, the corresponding checkbox is checked.  If the property has an undefined value, the box is unchecked.  Also, WiX conditionals using set / unset properties treat the property as a bool with respect to whether it is defined and *not* what it's value is.  E.g. if you set the value to "0", the conditional testing the property will return true.

[Further discussion of Checkbox semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992006/how-to-set-a-check-box-to-unchecked-from-the-msiexec-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

Following the link provided by @imagi have helped me to add find out how to add the checkbox. I figured that I will paste the code here in case the given link will cease to exist one day:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="MyInstallDirDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
                ...
                <Control Id="DesktopShortcutCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="160" 
                         Width="290" Height="17" Property="INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT" 
                         CheckBoxValue="1" 
                         Text="Create a shortcut for this program on the desktop." />
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```