# Disable Checkbox in WIX with condition element

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7, wix-extension

I am trying to disable a Wix checkbox based on project configuration. So far it did not work. Does anybody know how to make it work?

```
<Control
  Id="cbxXXX"
  Type="CheckBox"
  Property="XXX"
  X="20"
  Y="100"
  Width="290"
  Height="12"
  Text="xxxx"
  CheckBoxValue="True"
>
  <Condition Action="disable>$(var.Project.Configuration) = "DEBUG</Condition>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old post but this is most likely because the dialog is created at run-time and you're trying to access compile-time variables i.e. pre-processor variables.

To work around this set a new property e.g.
`CONFIGURATION` to `$(var.Project.Configuration)`

Access the property like before:
`<Condition Action="disable">CONFIGURATION = "DEBUG" </Condition>`

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with WIX GUI modification, but one concept you need to know about MSI properties is that you can "undefine" them using Property={}.

Once defined with any value, a property fails a logical test such as NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE because the property checked has a value. NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE equals to "this property is undefined, it doesn't exist". To uncheck a check box in the GUI, this undefined state is what you need - I know it is very counterintuitive for a developer who would think the check state is due to values such as 0 for unchecked and 1 for checked. I am told VB6 developers may be more familiar with the "undefined concept".

See this thread for one discussion of MSI GUI: [How to set a check box to "unchecked" from the msiexec command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992006/how-to-set-a-check-box-to-unchecked-from-the-msiexec-command-line)